# Anonymous methods - C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, event-handling, anonymous-methods

I have a requirement to implement a single VB.NET instance of an application on a terminal server. To do this I am using code from the [Flawless Code](http://www.flawlesscode.com/post/2008/02/Enforcing-single-instance-with-argument-passing.aspx) blog. It works well, except in the code is written in C# and uses an anonymous method which is not supported in VB.NET.  I need to rewrite the following so that I can use it as an event in VB.NET.

```
static Form1 form;

static void singleInstance_ArgumentsReceived(object sender, ArgumentsReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (form == null)
            return;

        Action<String[]> updateForm = arguments =>
            {
                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                form.OpenFiles(arguments);
            };
        form.Invoke(updateForm, (Object)e.Args); //Execute our delegate on the forms thread!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Private Shared form As Form1

Private Shared Sub singleInstance_ArgumentsReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ArgumentsReceivedEventArgs)
    If form Is Nothing Then Return
    form.Invoke(New Action(Of String())(AddressOf updateFormMethod), e.Args)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub updateFormMethod(ByVal arguments As String())
    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    form.OpenFiles(arguments)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ondatra, thanks for the response, this looks like it could work however, when I try to implement it, I get a ''AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'System.Delegate' because type 'System.Delegate' is declared 'MustInherit' and cannot be created.' error. Again thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks Ondatra. That seems to work. Except now I keep getting that the form Is Nothing. I will work on that and let you know what I do to fix it. Once again, thanks to everyone who helped. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Ondatra, I figured out the form issue but now I am getting a 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException was unhandled
  Message="Parameter count mismatch."
  Source="System.Windows.Forms"' error. 
Any ideas? Hate to keep asking but just feel that I am so close to an answer now with all the help on here. Thanks again.

Comment: I got it (I think). It was thanks to a combination of both Ondatra and kek444's answers. 
I had to change the line, 

form.Invoke(New Action(Of String())(AddressOf updateFormMethod), e.Args)
to 
form.Invoke(New Action(Of String())(AddressOf updateFormMethod), New Object() {e.Args})

Thanks again for all the help....

Answer (score 4):

In VB.NET in VS 2010 you can do the following:

```
Shared form As Form1
Shared Sub singleInstance_ArgumentsReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ArgumentsReceivedEventArgs)
    If form Is Nothing Then Return

    Dim updateForm As Action(Of String()) = Sub(arguments)
                                                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
                                                form.OpenFiles(arguments)
                                            End Sub

    form.Invoke(updateForm, e.args)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi pb, thanks, I am using VS2008 however, it doesn't seem to like me declaring a Sub within a Sub. I get 'End Sub' must be preceded by a matching 'Sub'..

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
public void Somemethod()
{
    Action<String[]> updateForm = arguments =>
        {
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            form.OpenFiles(arguments);
        };
}
```

Would be the same as:

```
public void Somemethod()
{
    Action<String[]> updateForm = OnAction;
}

//named method
private void OnAction(string[] arguments)
{
    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    form.OpenFiles(arguments);
}
```

Then you do the VB.net transition easily, to something like this:

```
Public Sub SomeMethod()

    Dim updateForm As Action(Of String()) = New Action(Of String())(AddressOf Me.OnAction)
    Me.form.Invoke(updateForm, New Object() { e })

End Sub

Private Sub OnAction(ByVal arguments As String())
    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    form.OpenFiles(arguments)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks kek444, I think that I got it thanks you a combination of your answer and ondatra's answer....